# Generate Random Integer from Min to Max?

Tags: java, android, random

I want to generate a random Integer that is:

1. Inside the range [Min, Max] `inclusive`
2. The range can be [5,20], [-29, -3] or [-13, 13] (It can be in any range, positive or negative or in between)
3. The code is working fine in Android

What I got so far is this, but it seems not working with negative ranges !

```
1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
```

Comment: You [-3,-29] is on wrong position if you say [Min,Max],

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but the code still isn't correct with this fixed.  Also, `[5, -13]` is wrong too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: generating random number in a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/java-generating-random-number-in-a-range)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want

```
Min+(int)(Math.random()*((Max-Min) + 1));
```

However, I should point out that the range [-3,-29] has its min and max reversed.  (And the same with [5,-13] as was pointed out by Merlyn.)

If you want to just put in any two numbers for the range, a and b then use the code

```
int Min = Math.min(a,b);
int Max = Math.max(a,b);
```

That way you won't have to worry about the order.  This will even work for a==b.

Comment: Good catch.  I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int min = -100;
int max = 100;
Random rand = new Random();
return rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @param bound1 an inclusive upper or lower bound
 * @param bound2 an inclusive lower or upper bound
 * @return a uniformly distributed pseudo-random number in the range.
 */
public static int randomInRange(int bound1, int bound2) {
    int min = Math.min(bound1, bound2);
    int max = Math.max(bound1, bound2);
    return min + (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}
```

---

If the caller can guarantee that `bound1` will be less or equal to `bound2` than you can skip the step of figuring out the minimum and maximum bounds; e.g.

```
/**
 * @param min the inclusive lower bound
 * @param max the inclusive upper bound
 * @return a uniformly distributed pseudo-random number in the range.
 */
public static int randomInRange(int min, int max) {
    return min + (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}
```

---

I haven't tested this on Android, but it should work on any Java or Java-like platform that supports those methods in conformance to the standard (Sun) Java SE specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone mentioned that his min and max are reversed?  Because that's what is screwing up his code.

**EDIT**

The other thing that's messing up his code: it should be `Min +` not `1 +`

Comment: It has been mentioned, but no, that's not what's screwing up his code.

Comment: edited to add actual helpful suggestion instead of just snark.  Because it's the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

You would simply calculate the difference between min and max
example -30 and 30
to get:
delta <-- absolute value of (30 - (-30))
then find a random number between 0 and delta.

There is a post related to this already.
afterwards translate the number along the number-line by your constant min.

If using the Random class:
1) is added to the equation here for Random.nextInt(someInt) because nextInt returns:
someVal < someInt so you need to be sure to include the boundaries in the functions output.

Something about this code is makes me cautious:

```
return min + 
(int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}
```

When casting rounding doubles to cast to ints:

```
int someRandomDoubleRoundedToInteger = (int)(someDouble + 0.5)
```

Does it work? This is for my benefit, maybe some other newbies will be amused, or maybe I made a blunder so:

lets choose 1 and 10 to begin with.
Pick a number between 1 and 10 (Inclusive) I pick 10

Math.Random Excludes 0 and 1. so 0.9999999999999999 * (10 - 1 + 1) = 9.999999999999999 cast to int, so lob off everything after the decimal produces 9 the we add 1 to 9 to return 10. (using random anything from (.9 to .999999999999) also will produce 10

I want to choose 1 from between 1 and 10.

In this case the random method puts out it's closest value to zero say:
0.00000000000000001 * (10 - 1 + 1) cast to int is zero 0 We return 1+0. So that works.

Huh, seems to work. Looks like a very, very, very minor bias against 1 since we are never including "0"  as a possibility but it should be acceptable.

The method works, If the random generator evenly covers the entire area between 0 and 1.
How many different numbers can be represented between the {0,1} interval, are they evenly spaced?

I think it works.